# New Relic shows process named CacheService using 400MB

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, newrelic

We are hosting an MVC .NET site on Azure and have New Relic installed to monitor it. New Relic shows that there is a process named CacheService with the user 'system' that is using 400MB+

I'm struggling to work out what CacheService actually relates to. 
We aren't using the .NET cache.

Some more details:

We are also noticing a difference between the memory usage reported by Azure compared to the memory usage reported by NewRelic.

Azure shows memory peaking at 618MB for a server that has a max memory of 1790MB:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5L4K.png

New Relic shows the memory going up to 90+% usage every day:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLtXV.png

Comment: `CacheService.exe`, to the best of my knowledge, is Azure Cache (previously AppFabric). Are you *sure* you aren't using it?

Comment: We don't have an Azure Cache running.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the chart you are looking at this in Windows Server Monitor.  Here is the WMI query that we run to gather the memory details for the overall server:

`SELECT AvailableBytes, CommitLimit, CommittedBytes, ModifiedPageListBytes, StandbyCacheCoreBytes, StandbyCacheNormalPriorityBytes, StandbyCacheReserveBytes, FreeAndZeroPageListBytes FROM Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Memory`

This is run every 20 seconds and the results are averaged together once per minute to make a single metric for that minute. The image also shows that the time span covers a several day period which will cause further averaging that could skew things.

Process specific details are gathered from class in System.Diagnostics, mainly GetProcesses() and GetProcessByID().

Comment: Thanks Jacob. Can anyone explain why Azure would not show the same memory usage?